# Adding a space before each capital letter in a selected set of lines in a yaml file using sed

Tags: sed, grep

I want to write a regex for a shell script. It is used to match only this kind of lines in yml file. (lines with the tag **summary: Example Summary**)

```
summary: GetMembersSavedSearchesByMemberId
```

So What I want to do is add a space before each Uppercase letter and output like this

```
summary: Get Members Saved Searches By Member Id
```

I tried this regex

```
matchregex="summary[:][[:space:]].\([A-Z]\)"
replacement="summary: .\1"
sed -e "s/${matchregex}/${replacement}/g"
```

It is not working. What is the correct way of writing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
sed -E '/^summary:/ s/([a-z])([A-Z])/\1 \2/g'
```

Result:

```
summary: Get Members Saved Searches By Member Id
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\B[[:upper:]]/ &/g' file
```

Globally insert a space inside a word where the following character is uppercase.